# php - Current date in MySQL WHERE condition

Tags: date, replace

How to get current day's date for a MySQL query in my PHP code?

```
$sql = "SELECT id, d, d_s FROM s_e WHERE d_s = '2015-05-31'";
```

Comment: What's the type of `d_s`? What DBMS is used? What have you tried so far? So many questions, so few information ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, replace  `'2015-05-31'` with `current_date()`.